# How to convert Pandas object into R vector

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have the following object in R.

```
> obs_names
Index(['R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_33_GCGGTTGCATCC',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_33_AGGGAAGAGGCC',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_33_GGGTAGCTATCC',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_33_ATGACGTTGTCC',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_33_ACGACGTCACGG',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_33_TTCACTGACGGG',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_33_GCCGAAGAGTGG',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_33_ACGGGTTGGTGG',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_33_GGCACGTCAGCC',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_33_ACGCTCTTCCGG',
       ...
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_20_ACAATATGCCAA',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_20_CTGAACCAATCC',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_20_TTGTTGGAATCC',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_20_TTGCATGTGGCC',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_20_CTTCGCGTAGCC',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_20_GCAATGCGCTGG',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_20_TCTTTCCTTCGG',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_20_ATTAATTCCCAA',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_20_AGTGTATTTATT',
       'R210525_VH00236_71_AAAJGJVM5_SCI255_20_GGATTGGTTCGG'],
      dtype='object', length=3992)
```

It is actually a [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) class:

```
> class(obs_names)
[1] "pandas.core.indexes.base.Index"     "pandas.core.base.IndexOpsMixin"    
[3] "pandas.core.base.PandasObject"      "pandas.core.accessor.DirNamesMixin"
[5] "python.builtin.object"
```

How can I convert `obs_names` into plain R vector?

I tried this but failed:

```
> as.vector(obs_names)
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'any'
```

Comment: Can you add `dput(obs_names)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah sorry. I got this message with dput: `> dput(adata$obs_names )
<environment>`

Comment: Try `reticulate::py_to_r(obs_names)`

Comment: @ShawnBrar It still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide code to create a sample of this object? Like 5 to 10 elements.

Comment: how were you able to print the `obs_name` in R? Did you just call `obs_name` or did you use `reticulate`?

Comment: @Onyambu I just call obs_name. I was converting Monocle3 object to Anndata using `adata <- zellkonverter::SCE2AnnData(cds); obs_name <- adata$obsname`

Answer (score 1):

you can change the object in python first using rpy2 package

```
import pandas as pd
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector

# Assuming you have a Pandas Index object called 'pandas_index'
r_vector = StrVector(pandas_index)
```

and then use rpy2 R package to read in R:

```
library(rpy2)
# Assuming you have an R vector called 'r_vector'
r_vector
```

OR other method to do that is you can use reticulate package in R:

```
# Convert the Pandas object to an R vector
r_vector <- reticulate::py_to_r(pandas_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but if anyone stumbles on this question, this worked for me:

`as.vector(obs_names$values)`